# Jsf application throws java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Connection closed

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have a JSF2.2 application on Glassfish4.1. It was deployed in July, 2016. Everything was fine. But suddenly from the last few days, i see the following exception in logs.

> > [2016-09-19T22:34:07.390+0530] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=31 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1474304647390] [levelValue: 800] [[   errorAn established connection was aborted by
> >     the software in your host machine]]
>
> [2016-09-19T22:34:07.624+0530] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING]
>   [jsf.application.resource.unable_to_serve_from_library]
>   [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] [tid:
>   _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1474304647624] [levelValue: 900] [[   JSF1064: Unable to find or serve
>   resource, jquery/jquery-plugins.js, from library, primefaces.]]
>
> [2016-09-19T22:34:07.624+0530] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] []
>   [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] [tid:
>   _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1474304647624] [levelValue: 900] [[
>
> > java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Connection closed  at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.blockAfterWriteIfNeeded(OutputBuffer.java:969)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:686)
> >         at
> >     org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:355)
> >         at
> >     org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:342)
> >         at
> >     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:161)
> >         at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(Unknown
> >     Source)     at
> >     com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:346)
> >         at
> >     javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:153)
> >         at
> >     org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:74)
> >         at
> >     javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:153)
> >         at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:643)   at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
> >         at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
> >         at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
> >         at filters.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:44)  at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
> >         at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
> >         at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
> >         at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
> >         at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
> >         at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
> >         at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
> >         at
> >     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
> >         at
> >     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
> >         at
> >     com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
> >         at
> >     com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
> >         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
> >     java.io.IOException: Connection closed  at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.asyncqueue.TaskQueue.onClose(TaskQueue.java:317)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.onClose(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:475)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.closeConnection(TCPNIOTransport.java:400)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection.doClose(NIOConnection.java:593)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection$5.run(NIOConnection.java:559)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.execute(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:234)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection.terminate0(NIOConnection.java:553)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOConnection.terminate0(TCPNIOConnection.java:292)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.writeCompositeRecord(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:169)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:87)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.processAsync(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:333)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:108)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:103)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeyEvents(SelectorRunner.java:414)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeys(SelectorRunner.java:383)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:347)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:278)
> >         ... 3 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection
> >     was aborted by the software in your host machine    at
> >     sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)   at
> >     sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)   at
> >     sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)     at
> >     sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)     at
> >     sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)  at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOUtils.flushByteBuffer(TCPNIOUtils.java:149)
> >         at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.writeCompositeRecord(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:158)
> >         ... 16 more ]]
>
> pls advice

Comment: You need to present some code to us. But you should check where you closed all the input and output streams.

Comment: @YoungMillie i have added a couple of log lines at the start. kindly have a look. I m sure it is not about closing input and output streams.

Comment: have seen that, did you also read the printed stack? Its talk about connection been closed at some point. That where am talking about.